# Activity Lifecycle: startActivityForResult and press Back Button

Tags: java, android, lifecycle

Is there a method of the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) which is called if the user presses the back button, but not if the the method startActivityForResult() is called? I couldn't find a method by testing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, I just didn't saw the solution, but here it is:

By calling startActivityForResult(), the methods onPause() and onStop() of the original activity are called.

When pressing the Back Button, the methods onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() are called.

So the difference is the onDestroy() method.

Answer (score 6):

> Normally, it will be onResume() followed by onActivityResult().
>   However it's possible, though unlikely, that the calling activity will
>   have been killed at some point while the user worked with the other
>   activity; this happens when the system runs out of memory, at which
>   point it starts killing stuff, starting from the 'most inactive'. In
>   that case, I imagine it would go through onCreate(), onStart(),
>   onResume() and then finally onActivityResult().
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869832/323696

The answer I quoted above is correct, except for the explanation for when the *calling activity* is killed, or finished(), before the *called activity* completes.

In that case, when the calling activity, **Activity #1**, resumes after having called another activity, **Activity #2**, using **startActivityForResult**, the method **onActivityResult** in **Activity #1** is called *BEFORE* **onResume**.

This is important to know if you are instantiating your SQLite Database objects from within onResume in **Activity #1**.  If so, you will also need to instantiate the object from within **onActivityResult**, when returning from **Activity #2**.

For more information, read about the '***startActivityForResult method***' at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.

I haven't been able to find a LifeCycle Diagram depicting this.  The step for when returning from an activity for result is always summed up within a text description in the LifeCycle images, stating '*User Returns to the activity*', or '*The activity comes to the foreground.*'